# Expand filtered nodes ancestors after match?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress-windows-ui, xtratreelist

I have a TreeList control and I've enabled the AutoFilterRow and the Extended filter mode.  The filtering works fine, if I type in the filter row it does narrow down the nodes displayed, but if the ancestors are still collapsed the node matching the filter remains hidden.  Is there a setting, or some code I can add, which after the filter is applied will ensure all nodes which match automatically have their ancestor nodes expanded so that the matching node becomes visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to update to the latest DevExpress version, 15.2, which has a [ExpandNodesOnFiltering](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeListOptionsBehavior_ExpandNodesOnFilteringtopic) setting on the TreeList to enable this functionality.